GSheets countif formula when the cell contains two numbers
this is the formula im using:
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$6,"<=3")
this are the cells im trying to count to:

What I want to happen:
count in range all those within 1-3. so the result of the formula should be 5. but the formula can't read the 1 & 8 in the first cell.
how should i go about this? regex or something else?

If you're trying to count all the values that are below 3, you can write the formula as =SUM(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(B2:B6, " & ")),"<=3"))
First thing to do is to split the numbers by & and convert the result to array. Once that is done, you can use COUNTIF to count and get a sum of the count values.

This may be much easier than expected.
Your formula =COUNTIF(B$2:B$6,"<=3") is giving you a 2 because only B4 and B6 are numbers and therefore counted by COUNT(). The other cells are strings. If you want to include these in your count you may want to try using COUNTA(), instead.
=COUNTA(B:B) yields 5, as expected/demanded.
